# Is there a way to force Firefox to define the transform origin of an SVG path to be relative to the path itself, rather than the SVG?

Tags: css, firefox, svg, transform

I'm trying to use CSS to spin an SVG path and I can't get it working properly in Firefox.

Here are my styles:

```
path {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: spin 1s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

This works in Chrome but not Firefox. In Firefox, the animation works but the origin is relative to the SVG viewbox, not the path itself. I've learned that [this is apparently correct](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/), but why? Why do SVG paths behave differently than every other HTML element? It just seems counter intuitive.

The only alternative solution I've found is calculating the actual origin using the `width` and `height` of the viewbox and the `width`, `height`, `x`,and `y` coordinates of the path, and then using a fixed pixel value. While this works, it isn't nearly as convenient or practical as the Chrome solution. In fact, my path doesn't even have `x` or `y` attributes. It's position is described in the `d` attribute, so using this particular path, I'm not even sure how to make that calculation.

Is there a way to force Firefox to define the origin relative to the path, rather than the SVG? Perhaps a polyfill or something? I'd really like to accomplish this using the simple method that Chrome supports.

Comment: Why, because [the specification says so](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do SVG paths behave differently than every other HTML element?

Two reasons:

1. SVG elements are not HTML elements, and are not subject to the same rules.
2. The defined behaviour is consistent with the way percentage coordinates work elsewhere in SVGs.

A new  property called [`transform-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) has been proposed that will allow you to alter the behaviour of `transform-origin` for both HTML and SVG.

If and when browsers support this new property, you will be able to get behaviour that matches Chrome's current behaviour by using:

```
transform-box: fill;
```

FF has already implemented this, but it is not enabled by default yet (AFAIK).

For now, you will need to calculate the centre coordinates yourself.  Or, alternatively, rearrange your SVG so that the path is centred on the origin and use a combination of transforms to do your rotation.

For example:

```css
.mypath {
  fill: red;
  animation: spin 1s linear 0s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<svg width="400px" height="400px">
  <g transform="translate(200,200)">
    <!-- path centred on (0,0) -->
    <path d="M -100,-100 L 100,-100 100,100 -100,100 Z" class="mypath"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```